What exactly are characteristic functions of sets when constructing Boolean models?
Reading J. L. Bell's Set Theory --- Boolean-Valued Models and Independence Proofs. This is how the introduction of Boolean models is motivated:

Suppose that for each set $x ∈ V$ we are given a characteristic function for $x$, that is, a function $c_x$ taking values in the Boolean algebra $2 = \{0, 1\}$ such that $x ⊆ \mathrm{dom}(c_x)$ and, for all $y ∈ \mathrm{dom}(c_x)$, $c_x(y) = 1$ iff $y ∈ x$. It is clear that all information about $x$ is carried by $c_x$, so it is natural to identify $x$ with $c_x$. If we perform this identification for all $x ∈ V$, we see that $V$ may, in a natural sense, be regarded as a class of two-valued functions.

I'm mostly fine with this, although it's unclear to me why we allow the domain of $c_x$ to vary so much. I initially thought this was justified by the inability to make the domain equal $V$, but I eventually realized we could've just made the domain $V_{\mathrm{rank}(x)}$. Why wasn't this done?
My main problem comes when the author generalizes this approach to arbitrary Boolean algebras $B$ and defines the truth-value of each formula in $V^{(B)}$. To define the truth-value of atomic formulas, the author uses this (among other things) as motivation:

Finally, we shall require that the Boolean truth value of restricted formulas like $∃x ∈ uφ(x)$ and $∀x ∈ uφ(x)$ depend only on the Boolean truth values of $φ(x)$ for those $x$ which are actually in $\mathrm{dom}(u)$. Moreover, in evaluating the Boolean truth value of such formulas, we agree to be guided by our original case of characteristic functions, where, for $x ∈ \mathrm{dom}(u)$, the ‘truth value’ of the formula $x ∈ u$ is $u(x)$.

It's unclear to me what the characteristic function is in this context, as it was never generalized to the case $B \neq 2$. The final definition of the atomic formula $u \in v$ is
$$\left[u \in v\right]^{(B)} = \bigvee_{y \in \mathrm{dom}(v)} (v(y) \land [u = y]^{(B)})$$
Since these functions were basically left undefined, I assume they're generalized in the simplest possible way, i.e. $v(y) = 1$ iff $y \in v$, otherwise $v(y) = 0$. Now, however, it's completely unclear to me what this is even accomplishing in the above formula. After all, we are already iterating over $\mathrm{dom}(v)$, so it should be meaningless.
I'm also not entirely sure on the difference between $v(y)$ and $[y \in v]^{(B)}$ in this case. I mean, they clearly evaluate to different numbers, but if we can with certainty "know" whether or not $y \in v$, why do we even care about $[y \in v]^{(B)}$? (My rough intuition is that this expression will eventually measure the degree to which $y \in v$ in a certain model or something like that, but I haven't yet gotten to that part so I don't know how much this is accurate.) Basically, since we can't definitively determine whether or not any two definable sets are equal (e.g. $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) = \aleph_1$) in ZFC, rather it depends on the model, to define characteristic functions a model must've been fixed beforehand. But should these truth-values we're defining then also depend on the model? Is that the intention?
I know I've asked a lot of questions, but I'd appreciate answers to any of them. Thanks.

The (generalizations of) characteristic functions are the elements of $V^{(B)}.$ In the case of $B=2,$ each element is a function with codomain $2,$ i.e. a characteristic function.

@spaceisdarkgreen how do we then know which one to pick in the definition of $[u \in v]$? If they aren't required to send elements of $v$ to $1$, they don't necessarily agree on $\mathrm{dom}(v)$, so the above isn't a good definition.

I don't understand... there's nothing to "pick". $u$ and $v$ are given elements of $V^{(B)}$

Maybe this is the issue: in the case $B=2$ you have a one-to-one correspondence between $V$ and $V^{(2)}$ by, for each $x\in V,$ choosing some $c_x\in V^{(2)}$ that represents it in the obvious way. But $V^{(2)}$ isn't just the "chosen representatives", it contains all of the "characteristic functions for each $x\in V$, for all the different "possible domains" (and for that matter, for all of the possible characteristic functions of the elements of $x$).

(I shouldn’t have said “one-to-one correspondence” above as if it’s surjective… indeed part of the point is that it’s not.)

Okay, thanks! That cleared up part of the problem for me. But which element of $V^{(B)}$ specifically is $v(x)$, then? Is it simply the one that sends the elements of $v$ to $1$ and everything else to $0$?

This is like asking "which element of $\mathbb N$ is $n$?" It's just some element of $V^{(B)}$ (look back to the definition of $V^{(B)}$ to know what it means for something to be an element of $V^{(B)}$). There is no corresponding element of $V$ that you're trying to "match it up" to.

I mean, we're defining $\left[u \in v\right]$. If $v(x)$ is in the definition, $v(x)$ must depend on $v$ somehow. In the case of $V^{(2)}$, it's perfectly well defined (up to the domain): $v(x)$ is the function that sends all $x \in v$ to $1$ and all others in its domain to $0$. What's $v(x)$ in general?

Ok, I see now that you asked "which element of $V^{(B)}$ is $v(x),$" not "which element of $V^{(B)}$ is $v$", which makes less sense, since $v(x)$ is not an element of $V^{(B)},$ it is an element of $B$. That's like asking "what element of the range of $f$ is $f(x)$"... whichever one it is. $v$ is some element of $V^{(B)},$ which means by definition it's some function from a subset of $V^{(B)}$ to $B.$ For an $x\in \operatorname{dom}(v),$ $v(x)$ is the value of the function $v$ at $x.$ That's what it is. What you say after "in the case of $V^{(2)}$" doesn't make sense.

I'm sorry, I finally got it now. I didn't realize that the characteristic function was literally the element that we're working with. I thought the element of $V^{(B)}$ on the left hand side $v$ and the function on the right hand side $v(x)$ were different objects. Thanks!
